# Why doesn't the input text field retain its value when disabled?

Tags: angular, forms, input, storybook, angular-storybook

I am working on a simple **input field** using **Angular** which is running in **StorybookJS**. The problem that I am facing is that, the input text field is not retaining its value when `disabled` is set to true.

So what is happening is that when I type "**hello**" text manually into the input field as follows:
[image]

And when I set the `disabled` property to `true`, the input field is disabled but, not retaining the value "hello" and instead, it is showing an empty text which is not correct.

[image]

Nonetheless, below the code to which I described above.

In **input.component.html**

```
<input [formControl]="inputValue" />
<div *ngIf="inputValue.invalid && inputValue.touched">
  <small *ngIf="inputValue.errors" class="error-text">This field is required.</small>
</div>
```

In **input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent {
  @Input() value: string = '';
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  // Create a FormControl to handle the input value and validation
  inputValue: FormControl = new FormControl();
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inputValue = new FormControl(
      { value: this.value, disabled: this.disabled },
      [Validators.required]
    );
  }
}
```

In **Input.stories.ts**

```
import { InputComponent } from './../../app/input/input.component';
import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/angular';
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

const meta: Meta<InputComponent> = {
  component: InputComponent,
  title: 'Basic Components/InputComponent',
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [InputComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    }),
  ],
  args: {},
  render: (args: InputComponent) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
  }),
  argTypes: {},
};
export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<InputComponent>;

export const Default: Story = {
  args: {
    value: '', 
    disabled: false,
  },
  render: (args) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
    template: `
        <form>
          <app-input [value]="value" [disabled]="disabled"></app-input>
          <!-- Adding an error message display in the story -->
          <div *ngIf="!value && value !== null">
            <small class="error-text">This field is required.</small>
          </div>
        </form>
      `,
  }),
};
```

Can I get some help on this to why the input text field is not retaining the entered value when disabled? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, the FormControl is first initialized with the value, and then the disabled property is set if needed. This way, the input field will retain its value when you set the disabled property to true:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: string = '';
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  // Create a FormControl to handle the input value and validation
  inputValue: FormControl;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Initialize the FormControl with the value
    this.inputValue = new FormControl(this.value, [Validators.required]);

    // Set the disabled property as needed
    if (this.disabled) {
      this.inputValue.disable();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and the issue still persists.